# CodedUI tests are not running on test controller / agent

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have been unable to get my CodedUI test project to run. The goal is to have it run on a separate machine (virtual machine). I've configured the test controller and agent on the VM. I've also set it to run as interactive process (details below). When I run my build it partially succeeds and the following test error is reported:

> Error calling Initialization method for test class XXXX.CodedUI:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: To
>   run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test
>   agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How
>   to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests That Interact with the
>   Desktop" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255012)

I've performed the following steps:

I've installed a Test Controller and Test Agent to VM (separate from TFS server)

My Test Controller was set "Register test controller with Team Project Collection". I've removed the checkbox! This caused a different error when running my build so I removed the checkbox.

My Test Agent is set to the test controller - set to interactive process - screen saver disabled

I have added a Test settings file to my solution.

- Test Execution Method: Remote Execution
- Controller shows my controller
- Manage Test Controllers shows my Test Agent as Ready!!

Resources I used:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695837.aspx

After performing all the steps I'm still getting the same error. What could the problem be? My test settings seems to correctly point to the test controller. The test controller and agent seems to be configured correctly. Do I need to use Lab Management to have these tests run on a VM?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you purposely running test cases during a build? If not, remove associated codedUI tests from your build definition. Your build should succeed. If you are running codedUI tests as CI or something during your build, then you must make sure that the BUILD agent/controller is set to run in interactive mode as well.

Comment: @JeffX Yes, I'm purposely running test cases during the build. This is going to be a build that kicks off my CodedUI tests. I wasn't aware that the build agent/controller needed to be run in interactive mode as well. I will give that a try and get back to you. If this works, I'll let you know and you can post the answer for an up vote. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure a Standard Environment in Lab management so that tfs knows where you are sending the tests.

http://nakedalm.com/standard-environments-for-automated-deployment-and-testing/

Should only take you a few minutes to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative set up is the following (without Lab Management environment):

1) do NOT register test controller with a Team Project Collection

2) have your agent set up to interact with desktop

3) in your solution - create testsettings file for the coded UI test run, point it to your test controller

4) in your build definition - set up automated tests to use this newly created test settings file

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to run coded UI test in MTM when build is triggering in TFS2015. set up is done with test agent and test controller and created LabEnvironment. When I trigger build then build is success but test case is not executed showing below error .Enabled interactive window in test agent.

MTM, Test agent , test controller, TFS installed in my same machine (Local machine)

I'm purposely running test cases during the build. This is going to be a build that kicks off my CodedUI tests.

Error calling Initialization method for test class CodedUITestProject.CodedUITest1: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: To run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests That Interact with the Desktop" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255012) If you are running the tests as part of your team build, you must also set up the build age